# Using string variable as function parameter in @Bean method

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have class CommandGenerator that should dynamically return the inheritors of abstract class command depending on the received String msg. How can I do this? At the moment there is such a code that gives an error:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

```
@Service
public class CommandGenerator<T extends Command> {

    @Autowired
    List<CommandFactory<T>> commandFactories;
    private List<T> commands;

    @Bean
    public T generateCommand(String msg) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to call `generateCommand` multiple times, why does it have a `@Bean` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example looks strange, as @tgdavies noticed. Depends on what you mean with "should dynamically return the inheritors of abstract class": as it is, it looks like that `CommandGenerator` should be "the" bean (as is correctly annotated), and the method `generateCommand` to generate/retrieve the `Command` should be called while performing business logic. If you want to generate just a `Command` bean (in a certain [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)) from configuration or other parameters, then there are (at least) two ways:

- one is to use a [`@Value`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) to read the string from somewhere (not just configuration);
- another similar idea, but that I like more (as it is easier to not use field injection) is to use [`@ConfigurationalProperties`](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) and change the bean signature to use the object which encapsulates the string you need.

Yet, I would put the bean definition in a `@Configuration` annotated class, not a `@Service` one:

```
@Configuration
public class CommandConfiguration {

  //other bean definitions

  @Bean
  public Command command(CommandGenerator generator, String message) {
    return generator.generateCommand(message);
  }

}
```